# Alternative inputs controls for putting items in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface

Might not be the BEST fit for Stack Overflow, but I trust you guys, and a lot of you are the best web devs around, so here goes:

I have a web app with several groups of phrases.  For each group, you put 4 "answers" in order of most like you (it's a personality test).

I made a fancy svg and responsive, game-like system where there are 4 clouds that you click on in the order that you want.  But it's html5/css3/svg effects with a lot of transformations and it only works on some browsers
[image]

I don't know any design "theory", but what I need to figure out is how to make an extremely simple, fully cross-browser and cross-device way to do the same TYPE of thing.

examples:

1. list each group of 4 answers with a dropdown box next to each one where you can select 1-4
2. drag and drop them to put them in order (jquery.  but this won't work on touchscreens)
3. put and "up/down" arrow next to each one (like some windows dialogs)
4. use radio buttons?
5. YOUR SUGGESTION HERE

I hope the question is clear.  I'm a web developer looking for a cross-device "ui widget" (or idea) for putting sets of 4 "answers" in order.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Numbers 1, 3, 4 should be easy enough and will be cross browser, so what is the issue?

Comment: for one, they those methods leave a "starting order"  which I'm trying to avoid (hence the clouds with a horizontal staggered layout.  But also, the dropdowns are kind of annoying, and would make it a little difficult to see the priority. (I'd like the answer to phisically end up in order)  I don't know how the radio buttons would need to be layed out to select 1-4 for each.  I guess I'm looking for something very elegant and simple that I hadn't thought about.  or a link to a list of "ordering" widgets

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea regarding this. Hope this will be helpful.[image]

Please do comment if you have any problem to understand my above image.